# Benefit of DGPS for relative accuracy and speed measurements for receivers close-by each other

Tags: gps, accuracy

Consider that we are interested only in the speed and relative position accuracy of GPS receivers (i.e. their absolute try position on earth is NOT important). These receivers are all in a  90m x 90m area.
In this case, does it really matter whether we use DGPS or not?
For relative position/location accuracy, I think DGPS won't help much because the errors it corrects affect the receivers in a similar fashion (assuming that they see the same satellites, which is a reasonable assumption?)
Does DGPS help improve speed accuracy (assuming Doppler based speed)?

Answer (score 1):

DGPS or RTK provided corrections that behave like a translation for absolute GPS measurements, so for relative measurements and speed over small areas. absolute GPS device seems to be enough.

[this post explains more this subject](http://www.gpsfarmmap.com/en/pages/gps_accuracy/)

[this video explains more advanced relative positioning techniques](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=BH149tSPrhs)

Comment: Thanks geogeek. I understand that relative position accuracy over small areas will not benefit from DGPS/SBAS. I wanted to get more clarification on the speed. We are interested in the absolute speed of a receiver. Essentially, will the accuracy of the Speed over ground reported in the NMEA data (with respect to its true speed) change/benefit from having SBAS versus not having it?

Comment: i don't know your required speed accuracy but this post may help you http://gpsactionreplay.free.fr/index.php?menu=6&choice=5